# Adding Arbitrary Execution to CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm setting up the build environment for an academic project using cmake, and I have some custom python scripts that generate some of my source files. Consequently, I need my build sequence to run these scripts, but I can't figure out how to get cmake to run arbitrary scripts and programs. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [add_custom_command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command) documentation

Example:

> add_custom_command(OUTPUT your_generated_file.cpp COMMAND python your_python.py)
>   add_executable(your_binary your_generated_file.cpp)

This should call python with your script and then build executable from generated file